# PhpStorm searching in project tool window

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm 10.0.4

When I start typing characters in project tool window it searchs for files containing typed text. 
[image]

Is it possible to change this behavior so only files that begins with typed text would be matched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to change this behavior so only files that begins with typed text would be matched?

AFAIK no. There are no GUI settings for this at all.

Plus, this [Speed Search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/speed-search-in-the-tool-windows.html) is used in many places/tool windows and search logic is the same.

---

**P.S.** If you need to search for files .. why not try more appropriate (in general sense) `Navigate | File...` instead?

Speed Search only finds items in already expanded nodes (as it's a basic search on already displayed text) .. but `Navigate | File...` will look for files everywhere in the project.

Comment: I would like to use to focus selection on some file. Like it is in Win explorer - you type begining of file name and it selects and scrolls window to matched file. A matter of habit.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible directly but you can create and use a scope for that.

Open `Settings` and go the `Appearance & Behaviour` -> `Scopes`. Create a new scope, give it a name (let's say "My Files") and put `file:*/c*` in the Pattern edit box.

In the big list of files under the Pattern edit box you can preview its effects. The files that are included in the scope are colored in green, the directories that contain included files are colored in blue.

This simple pattern selects only the files whose name start with `c`, in all directories. You can use slightly more complex filters using wild cards, include or exclude entire directories etc. With a little practice you can create filters that match usual needs pretty well.

When you are pleased with the scope definition, close the `Settings` box and go back to the `Project` view. Click on the arrow next to `Project` and you'll get a list of views of the project files. All the scopes you created should be there. Select "My Files" and only the files (and directories) included in that scope will be displayed in the `Project` view.

It is not a dynamic filter, you have to work a little to set it up, but it is useful when you work on large projects, with thousands of files, and you need to hide the files not important for your task.

Comment: Useful option however it not fits my requirements.

Comment: My question is about some other behaviour but about this Project window. Do you know, is there a way to jump to the next found pattern ? Like F3 or Alt+F3 that is used in this situations - where you find something but want to find next with same pattern. I cant find a way to do this in Project Tool Window

Comment: @Anton If you have a question then [ask a new question](/questions/ask). Don't ask it in a comment to another question or answer. Nobody can benefit from your question or my answer this way. Our conversion here is read by us and by the author of the question (the three of us are notified by SO about it) and probably by very few other persons that happen to reach this answer. I don't know the answer to your question (I stopped using Idea products about three years ago). If you [ask a new question](/questions/ask) then a lot of people can see it in the homepage and can help you with an answer.

Comment: @axiac ouraight bro ty